# Reduce Browserify bundle of react.min.js and react-dom.min.js

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I want to bundle some React libs with Browserify and `--require` them, but was put off by the file size.

I use the following Browserify command:

```
browserify path/to/react.min.js path/to/react-dom.min.js > libs.js
```

Now, react.min.js is 21k, react-dom.min.js is 122k, but libs.js results in a whopping 269k. Surely there is not a Browserify overhead of 126k? When I look at libs.js there is a lot of added (unminified) React code. Where does this come from?

Comment: So this looks like a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922208/how-to-keep-browserify-bundle-size-sensible-when-using-requires-for-thirdparty-s). Also I found this blog post that talks about remedies (https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/12/reduce-the-size-of-your-react-applications/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Browserify is resolving the `require` call(s) in `react-dom` to the `react` module in `node_modules`. The `package.json` for that module specifies `main` as `react.js` - so you end up with a bundle that contains the the non-minified source in addition to `react.min.js`.

Note that if you bundle only `react.min.js`:

```
browserify \
--require ./node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js:react \
> bundle-react.js
```

The bundle size is only slightly larger than `react.min.js`:

```
ls -l node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js
... 21339 Dec 23 09:43 node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js

ls -l bundle-react.js
... 22006 Dec 23 11:56 bundle-react.js
```

To solve the problem, you need to tell Browserify to exclude `react` and `react-dom`, as you are going to provide an alternate mechanism for their being required - that is, you are going to specify the `--require` option:

```
browserify \
--exclude react \
--require ./node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js:react \
--exclude react-dom \
--require ./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js:react-dom \
> bundle-lib.js
```

The bundle size should now be much closer to the combined, minified files:

```
ls -l node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js
... 21339 Dec 23 09:43 node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js

ls -l node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js
... 123996 Dec 23 09:43 node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js

ls -l bundle-lib.js
... 146227 Dec 23 11:39 bundle-lib.js
```

You should then be able to create an application bundle that requires `react` and `react-dom` from your library bundle. Note that the Browserify command to create the application bundle should specify the `--exclude` option for `react` and `react-dom` - so that they are required from the library bundle and not from `node_modules`:

```
browserify \
--exclude react \
--exclude react-dom \
app.js > bundle-app.js
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you. I'd much rather have Browserify and UglifyJS take care of it, but the build size difference is huge! When I create a `bundle-libs.js` with the unminified versions, `NODE_ENV=production` and pipe through UglifyJS, I end up with a 280k sized file. Is Facebooks minifier so much better than UglifyJS?

Comment: I've not looked at it closely, but there are lots of files/modules in the `lib` directories inside `react` and `react-dom`. Each of those will get some Browserify boilerplate. It's possible that the mechanism used in the minified `dist` files is less verbose. Also, if you are using UglifyJS via a Browserify transform, the minification won't be applied to Browserify's boilerplate - only to the content of the modules imported into the bundle.